# How can i fill DataFrame's data by other row's value in a given condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to fill some rows' values use other rows' value.

let me list an example:

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'ba'], [1,2,3,np.nan,np.nan]]).T

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
    0    1
0   a    1
1   b    2
2   c    3
3  aa  NaN
4  bb  NaN
```

what i want is to `fill df.loc[3, 1]` with value of `df.loc[0, 1],`

`df.loc[4, 1]` with `df.loc[1, 1]`

because a given condition `('a' and 'aa'(loc[3,1] and loc[0, 1])` have same

`first 'a', 'b' and 'bb' shared 'b')`

is there any good methods to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible combine values by first letter with forward filling use:

```
df[1] = df.groupby(df[0].str[0])[1].ffill()
print (df)
    0  1
0   a  1
1   b  2
2   c  3
3  aa  1
4  ba  2
```

If need replace by first non missing value use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['aa', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'ba'], [np.nan,2,3,1,np.nan]]).T
print (df)
    0    1
0  aa  NaN
1   b    2
2   c    3
3   a    1
4  ba  NaN

df[1] = df.groupby(df[0].str[0])[1].transform('first')
print (df)
    0  1
0  aa  1
1   b  2
2   c  3
3   a  1
4  ba  2
```

Answer (score 0):

using `map` I can only think of this:

```
map_val = df.dropna().set_index(0).to_dict()[1]
df[1] = df[1].fillna(df[0].map(lambda x:map_val[x[0]]))
```

**df**

```
    0   1
0   a   1
1   b   2
2   c   3
3   aa  1
4   ba  2
```